# Default startup directory behavior in Dymola 2022

Tags: python, dymola

I just noticed an odd behavior in Dymola 2022, and I wonder if and how can I take care of it from the Python interface.

Odd behavior, because I expect Dymola to consistently set the working directory at `.\Documents\Dymola` at startup, unless told otherwise.

However, when I instantiate Dymola from its Python interface, at startup the working directory is set according to the setting `Tools > Options > Settings > Save startup directory` as follows:

- **`Do not save`** - then when I instantiate Dymola, the current directory is set as the directory where the python environment is open. Possibly interesting here:

  - the directory where the python environment is open **is not** the directory where the function is located.

    - Example: in VSCode `open folder > .\project`, the function is in `.\project\functions\dymIO\instantiateDymola.py`, then the Dymola working directory at startup is set at `.\project`
- **`Save this directory > .\Documents\Dymola`** - then the current directory is set reliably at `.\Documents\Dymola`

One solution/fix would be to set the working directory after Dymola is instantiated, I am aware of it.

My question is rather to get an understanding of what might be going on with this behavior, and if there is a possibility to take care of it right at startup rather than afterwards

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what is happening with Python at the moment, but I can answer what happens inside Dymola:

1. When you start a program from Start-Menu the current directory is as default set to the installation directory of the program (in this case Dymola).
2. *Not important*: When Dymola is started it first ensures that `.\Documents\Dymola` exists.
3. *Not important*: If the environment variable `DYMOLAWORKDIRECTORY` is not set it is set to `.\Documents\Dymola`
4. If the current directory is the same as the installation directory of Dymola then it sets current directory to `.\Documents\Dymola` - otherwise it keeps the current directory. This allows you to make a short-cut "Start Dymola Here!"
5. And then the settings where you might have changed 'Startup Directory' is processed.

But I don't know why the Python-interface changes current directory to `.\project`, and if you could change current directory in Python.